# List all files in all directory ( MemoryError )

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory, error-handling

I wrote this code to list all files and subdirectories in given path, also to list files inside archive and then write them together in one file. This is code .

```
import os

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import zipfile
import rarfile


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askdirectory()

l1 = []
ls1 = []

k1 = []
ks1 = []

z1 = []
r1 = []

filenamez = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        l = os.path.join(dirname ,subdirname)
        ls = os.path.join('in {} is {}'.format(dirname ,subdirname))
        ls1.append(ls)
        l1.append(l)
        l3 = os.walk(l)
        # print (l)
        for root,dirs, files in l3:
            for f in files:
                a = os.path.join(root,f)
                filenamez.append(a)
                for zips in filenamez:
                    if str(zips).endswith('.zip'):
                        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zips)
                        zname = zip.namelist()
                        for zn in zname:
                            zn = ('in {} is {}'.format(zips,zname))
                            z1.append(zn)
                for rars in filenamez:
                    if str(rars).endswith('.rar'):
                        rar = rarfile.RarFile(rars)
                        rname = rar.namelist()
                        for rn in rname:
                            rn = ('in {} is {}'.format(rars,rname))
                            r1.append(rn)

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        k = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
        ks = os.path.join('in {} is {}'.format(dirname,filename))
        ks1.append(ks)
        k1.append(k)
        k3 = os.walk(k)
        for root,dirs, files in k3:
            for f in files:
                a = os.path.join(root,f)
                filenamez.append(a)
                for zips in filenamez:
                    if str(zips).endswith('.zip'):
                        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zips)
                        zname = zip.namelist()
                        for zn in zname:
                            zn = ('in {} is {}'.format(zips,zname))
                            z1.append(zn)
                for rars in filenamez:
                    if str(rars).endswith('.rar'):
                        rar = rarfile.RarFile(rars)
                        rname = rar.namelist()
                        for rn in rname:
                            rn = ('in {} is {}'.format(rars,rname))
                            r1.append(rn)
```

In small size directories it works very well, but in big size it gives me MemoryError. Is there any other simple working code for my goal to list content of directories, subdirectories and archives or to simplify my code or to handle MemoryError ?

P.S. I am using 64 bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

If i get u right, u might need something like this:

it is putting output to file instead of console.

```py
import os
import shutil

rmpath = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('zip'):
            unpacked = os.path.join(root, name).replace('.zip', '_unpacked')
            shutil.unpack_archive(os.path.join(root, name), unpacked, 'zip')
            rmpath.append(unpacked)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('zip'):
            continue
        with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(os.path.join(root, name))

for path in rmpath:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```